# What is the best way to define a large array of data in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, csv

I have a PHP application which requires large 2D arrays of hard-coded data.  I currently just have this defined in a script which is included at the start of every script execution.

I would like to know if anyone has a better idea for how to do this.

My script looks something like the following. Except that I have many more rows and each row has many more fields.

```
function getData() {
    return array(
        1 => array('name'=>'a something', 'price'=>123, 'field1'=>1, 'field2'=>3, 'field3'=>2),
        2 => array('name'=>'b something', 'price'=>123, 'field1'=>3, 'field2'=>3, 'field3'=>2),
        3 => array('name'=>'c something', 'price'=>234, 'field1'=>2, 'field2'=>3, 'field3'=>2),
        4 => array('name'=>'d something', 'price'=>345, 'field1'=>8, 'field2'=>3, 'field3'=>2),
        5 => array('name'=>'e something', 'price'=>655, 'field1'=>12, 'field2'=>3, 'field3'=>2),
        6 => array('name'=>'f something', 'price'=>124, 'field1'=>11, 'field2'=>3, 'field3'=>2),
    );
}
```

Each row has the same fields.  So it is very much like a DB table result set.  I suppose I could put it in a DB table, but I find this script easier to edit and I would think it's much faster to run than querying a DB.

The problem with my current solution is that it can be hard to read because there are so many fields.  What I would like is a system that is easy to read and edit, but it must also be very  fast.

Would a DB table be better?  Or perhaps reading in a CSV file from a spreadsheet?

Comment: If it's relatively unchanging, why not memcache?

Comment: Actually yes memcache is a good option.  It doesn't solve the readability/editability, but would mean I could put the data in a spreadsheet/CSV and then make it fast with memcache.

Comment: @Jared Farrish: If it's relativly unchanging, why memcache?

Comment: @hakre - I was thinking of the static memory availability, but thinking about it now, it's perhaps overkill (and yes, memcache was built for dynamic data...). Without knowing the true size of the data, it's probably difficult to know if other approaches to loading data into memory would be "efficient enough". What I was thinking about, though, was the load into memory time.

Comment: @JaredFarrish: If you put it as an array into the code, it's already loaded when the code executes :)

Answer (score 2):

As a general idea, write your data is any way that's convenient, possibly CSV or something similar. Create a function that can process that data into the format you need. Cache the processed data so this doesn't need to be done every time.

```
function getData() {
    $cache = 'data.dat';

    if (file_exists($cache)) {
        return unserialize(file_get_contents($cache));
    }

    $data = <<<DATA
a something, 123, 1, 3, 2
b something, 123, 3, 3, 2
...
DATA;

    $data = array_map(function ($row) {
        $row = array_map('trim', explode(',', $row));
        return array_combine(array('name', 'price', 'field1', 'field2', 'field3'), $row);
    }, explode("\n", $data));

    file_put_contents($cache, serialize($data));
    return $data;
}
```

In the above example I'm just using a HEREDOC string to store the data. You may want to put that into an external CSV file, or an XML file that you can generate automatically from somewhere or whatever fits your needs.

If it's very large, storing it in a database may be a better idea. Something lightweight like SQLite will do.

Comment: Thanks, I like this answer.  I will do something like this.  I may use memcache to cache the data (as suggested by Jared Farrish) rather than a file, because that would make it easier to clear the cache if I change the data.

Comment: PS. Sorry I can't vote as I don't have enough reputation yet :)